# PHP CSV import script keeps loading after script has finished

Tags: php, laravel, csv

I create a small function to import a CSV file (around 5K lines). The import works fine, also the view at the bottom is returned, so it seems all code is executed. I see in the DB all lines have been inserted.

However, the page keeps on loading in the browser (unresponsive) after the redirect, and I see that PHP is still using an awe full lot of memory. I cannot figure out what is going on, anyone have any idea?

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $file = $request->file('eurofiberupload')->getRealPath();
    $handle = fopen($file, 'r');
    $firstrow=true;
    DB::table('upload')->truncate();
    while($row=fgetcsv($handle, 500, ';'))
    {
        if($firstrow===true)
        {
            $firstrow=false;
            continue;
        }

        Upload::create([
            'field0'=> $row[0],
            'field1' => utf8_encode($row[1]),
            'field2' => str_replace('NULL', 0, $row[3]),
            'field3' => floatval($row[4]),
            'field4' => floatval($row[5]),
            'field5' => $row[6],
            'field6' => $row[7],
            'field7' => floatval($row[8]),
        ]);
    }
    unset($row);
    fclose($handle);


    return redirect('/home')->with('success', 'All good!');

}
```

Comment: Does the while loop ever finish? you better use explicit check !== for fgetcsv() returning false

Comment: You can check the network tab in your developer tools to see why/what the browser keeps loading. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_development_tools

Comment: Not a solution to this question but you might want to try maatwebsite/excel @ https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel which makes importing CSVs very easy..

Comment: @john doe: this works easier for me, maatwebsite/excel is just overhead for csv files.
Eriks and KIKO: the loop finishes, it executes the redirect. I dont see anything in developer tools that keeps running, just see the tab getting stuck and php using a lot of memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can test if the returned row is null or has a value.Mmodify a bit your wile loop and do the following:

```php
{
    $file = $request->file('eurofiberupload')->getRealPath();
    $handle = fopen($file, 'r');
    $firstrow=true;
    DB::table('upload')->truncate();
    while(($row=fgetcsv($handle, 500, ';'))!=null)
    {
        if($firstrow===true)
        {
            $firstrow=false;
            continue;
        }

        Upload::create([
            'field0'=> $row[0],
            'field1' => utf8_encode($row[1]),
            'field2' => str_replace('NULL', 0, $row[3]),
            'field3' => floatval($row[4]),
            'field4' => floatval($row[5]),
            'field5' => $row[6],
            'field6' => $row[7],
            'field7' => floatval($row[8]),
        ]);
    }
    unset($row);
    fclose($handle);


    return redirect('/home')->with('success', 'All good!');

}
```

You can try

Comment: Same thing, page keeps loading, PHP keeps on running.
Guess it's just a bug in PHP somewhere

Comment: is there something in the error_log? normally at a certain time the browser could stop and show a REQUEST_TIME_OUT error/message. Is it the case?

Comment: Nope, nothing in the error log either. The browser does seem to recover after some time if you click on something. Maybe PHP just not exits the process as quickly as it should.

Comment: Possible. did you try in another browser?

Comment: yep, same issue. Up to a certain number of lines it runs without issues, after that it just goes nuts.

Comment: `return redirect('/home')->with('success', 'All good!');` that means your redirection to home is not working?

Comment: Everything is working, just the page is unresponsive after the redirect, and I see the PHP process is still consuming around 300mb of RAM
(It doesnt matter whether I redirect or where too, the issue seems related to the CSV processing)